# pointers to functions, with flexible types

Tags: c, pointers

I write a code with a connectivity list of a flexible type.
My database contains a list of nodes with data that might be a char* or a VERTEX* (struct defined by me). hence I defined the struct as with a field void*.
I also wish to have an operation which compares the strings in that field, so the list has a field defined:

```
DATA_EQ DataEqual
```

and defined a function which checks if the data of two nodes is equal:

```
typedef BOOL (*DATA_EQ) (void* pl, void* pr);
```

in order to define a DATA_EQ function for the list, in the case of string data, I created the following function in the .c file:

```
static BOOL stringDataEqual(char* pd1, char* pd2){

    return ( strcmp(pd1, pd2) == 0 );
}
```

Finally, I want this function to be defined on my list, so I wrote:

```
pList->dataEqual = stringDataEqual;
```

but I guess the fact that I tried to specify the void* as char* is not good.
I haven't worked with pointers to functions in the past, so I might have done some silly mistakes...
I got the warning (after running gcc to complie):

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ListCreate’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

I need my code to compile without any warnings, how do I solve/work around that?

Thanks ahead to anyone who helps,
Oded

Comment: What is the "database"? What does `\*` mean in the `typedef`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use casts to cast to and from void pointers. Your function becomes:

```
static BOOL stringDataEqual(void* pd1, void* pd2) {
    return ( strcmp((char*)pd1, (char*)pd2) == 0 );
}
```

You can call this function by casting the parameters to `void*`.